# In R shiny, How to create action button to transpose matrix if the view want to switch it?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

I created a matrix, and I want to input an action button to enable the user to control the view.

please use this [dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gDuISWjRFGYK-JC81jzVnFkpLx9nb_NA) and here is the error message as after clicking "transpose" button nothing happens: 
[image]

Here is the code

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
h2("India cities"),
DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"),
actionButton("go", "Transpose"),
dataTableOutput("mytabletranspose")
)

server <- function(input, output,session)
{output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
indiacities
})

observeEvent(input$go, {
  })

output$mytabletranspose<-renderDataTable({
t(mytable)
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsure what is the expected output. One option is to have the transposed table show up when the button is clicked in a new data table. This is relatively straight forward.

If you want the transposed table to appear as a new data table,

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  h2("India cities"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"),
  actionButton("go", "Transpose"),
  dataTableOutput("mytabletranspose")
)

server <- function(input, output,session){

  indiacities <- data.frame(city = c("Mumbai","Bangalore"),population = c(18,8.4),area_code = c("+91-22","+91-080"))

  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    indiacities
  })

  output$mytabletranspose <- DT::renderDataTable({
    req(input$go)
    t(indiacities)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

If you want to transpose the same table we will need to edit the original table `indiacities`. Because observer and reactive execute functions in their own environment we need to use the global assignment operator `<<-`

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  h2("India cities"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable"),
  actionButton("go", "Transpose"),
)

server <- function(input, output,session){

  indiacities <- data.frame(city = c("Mumbai","Bangalore"),population = c(18,8.4),area_code = c("+91-22","+91-080"))

  data <-  reactive({
    if(length(input$go) == 0){
      #Executed when the app is initializes
      return(indiacities)
    }else{
      indiacities <<- t(indiacities)
    } 
  })

  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    req(data())
    data()
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```